# What's the difference between "successive" and "consecutive"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives

What's the difference between "successive" and "consecutive"?

Comment: Having just answered one of your "difference between" questions, I wonder why you keep up this rapid-fire posting of questions about words you could easily look up in a dictionary.

Comment: I noticed this long time ago that just looking up words in a dictionary doesn't help me much, even if an attempt to compare synonyms is made there. One reason is because the examples given there are not that lively, so to say: they are rather short, taken out of the context, and it seems that they were deliberately chosen to confirm or fit in their formula/dogma that they had come up with in the process of their comparisons-making. Another reason is ... I don't want correct answers! Well, I mean I don't want things that would be 100% correct according to the dictionary, but ↓

Comment: Interesting - 13 'Whats the difference?' questions out of 17 in total...

Comment: would sound odd and too "stuffy" in daily conversation with ordinary people. One more reason is that it is always good to see how different people view the same question from different angles. Usually those who answer have something to say, which means that they have their own perspectives on the matter. Even if some answerers' opinions/views are wrong and get disproved later on the page, it is still very insightful to see what kind of (mis)concepts native speakers would have regarding different points related to their own language. All of this can hardly be obtained in any dictionary.

Comment: @CJM: I have a lot more, but I think I need to slow down a bit posting them otherwise I could be accused of spamming or even rep-whoring.

Comment: My main (and probably only) objection to these recent questions is that I feel they are not tagged sufficiently. I think they should all have the "word-choice" tag, as I [recently argued on meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/402/) (see also Kosmonaut's comment on that answer of mine), and the appropriate part-of-speech tag.

Comment: No problem. From now on I'll be using that tag too in such questions and if it's possible I will add this tag to those similar ones that I have already asked. I am still quite new here and don't know how to chose correct tag for questions , as well as many other things.

Comment: See also the related discussion on Meta: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/454/what-to-do-with-repeated-question-types

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First note that successive appears as a synonym of consecutive in dictionaries. (see Merriam Webster's entry  [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consecutive)).

Now compare these examples that I chose at random and extracted from the Corpus of [Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/):

**Consecutive**

- "his unprecedented string of consecutive appearances"
- "has own the best actor Emmy two consecutive times"
- "named person of the year for the second consecutive time"
- "account balance remains overdrawn for seven consecutive days"
- "the Irish made six consecutive NCAA Tournaments"

**Successive**

- "on successive laps, Chris passed three cars"
- "analysts say that successive governments failed to"
- "dramatic walk-off style in successive victories against the Seattle Mariners"
- "simultaneous and successive cognitive processes"
- "who have challenged successive military governments"

Here is what I observe in the examples (I hope I was lucky in my random choice of them):

In the examples that use *consecutive*, the fact that the events happened in a row without interruption seems to be something that the author wanted to emphasize.

However, in the examples that use *successive*, the fact that the events occur after each other with no interruption seems to play a secondary role. Notice that you can remove *successive* from some of these sentences and the meaning is not affected too much. If you remove *consecutive*, the impact is in general higher.

Comment: Thank you, Bruno!! I think You hit the mark and shed the light on question that has bugged me for so long. (And yes, of course I knew  that the two words were synonymous in such dictionaries like Merriam Webster).

Comment: Your penultimate paragraph is the key: the difference between *consecutive* and *successive* is that the former implies an **unbroken** sequence, while the latter does not.

Comment: Do you think then that the following question sounds okay: "Is it grammatically correct to have two consecutive gerunds in one sentence?" Or does is sound too formal? How would you phrase it?

Comment: @brilliant, your question sounds okay. But I think you would then have to provide an example, otherwise it would not be clear what exactly you were asking.

Comment: @Bruno Rothgiesser: Thank you. Example (just in case) would be something like "Keeping smoking while having a lung cancer is suicide"

Comment: I completely disagree.  Removing successive from the examples you found completely changes the meaning.  In the first and fourth examples for consecutive, while less precise, it is actually possible to remove consecutive and keep the same general meaning.

Comment: Another important aspect that *successive* can have but *consecutive* doesn't have is the notion of replacement.  Something that *succeeds* (trans.) something else generally takes its place - *consecutive* items can coexist, *successive* items often cannot.

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't any difference in denotation.  I suspect that "successive" is more apt to be used in a casual nontechnical context, and "consecutive" when the subject involves math or is otherwise technical.

Answer (score 0):

I think successive means without interruption, whereas consecutive implies a series with, perhaps, regular spaces between. For example, in history, kings succeed each other without interruption. Often the next king is chosen while the present king is still alive because it would be dangerous to leave a kingdom without a ruler. As to consecutive, "he was elected for the 6th consecutive time in a contest which was held every seven years.
ka

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE.This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective.

Answer (score -4):

*Successive* relates to two whereas *consecutive* involves more than two.

Comment: What is the source of this 'information'?