# Are 'consecutively' and 'successively' the same?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, differences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between “successive” and “consecutive”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5790/whats-the-difference-between-successive-and-consecutive)

Are 'consecutively' and 'successively' the same? Can they be used in place of each other freely? Does 'for 3 days consecutively..' and 'for 3 days successively..' mean the same ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Overall, yes *consecutively* and *successively* are equivalent.

On closer examination, there is a slight difference though.  In *consecutively*, there is no gap.  In *successively* there is just some order.

For instance "*in close/short succession*" is sometimes preferred to "*in succession*" to emphasize consecutiveness.

For instance:

- 1, 2 and 3 are ***consecutive*** numbers
- 1, 2 and 4 are ***successive*** numbers but they are not *consecutive*.

So for non discrete quantities you would probably prefer "successive" (as in "successive events") and for discrete quantities with no gaps you could use "consecutive" as in "2 consecutive days".

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. 'quick succession' is another phrase which emphasises consecutiveness.

Comment: Good answer. Addresses some of the subtleties that I left out. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I would quite confidently say that there is no difference; they both mean to follow in an uninterrupted order and to follow closely after another.

Interestingly:

Latin 'consectus' means 'followed closely'

Latin 'success' means 'followed closely'

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Karl for the Latin meanings. I think the difference is just common usage and what we get used to hearing. E.g 'its been raining for 3 days consecutively' is more common than 'its been raining for 3 days successively'.

Comment: Yes, @amit. I completely agree. Likewise, I would normally talk of 'consecutive' numbers rather than 'successive'. Like you say, I think it seems to have more to do with commonality than anything official.

Comment: Disagree. Alain is correct in his answer above, i.e., "1,2,3" vs "1,2,4." The etymology is immaterial.

Answer (score 0):

They have the same meaning and are both adverbs, but *consecutively* stresses immediacy in following and implies that no interruption or interval occurs:

> four consecutive days

*Successively* may apply to things of the same kind or class that follow each other regardless of length of interval between:

> four successive weekends